# ARC/MRR - is it a setting or what?

Tags: objective-c

Sorry, this is probably a very bad question. Ive just started to learn Obj-C and I dont understand this:

Do I somewhere choose if to use ARC/MRR/... for memorymanagement? is it a setting or does it depend on how i write my code?

Please explain like im 5 :)

Comment: It's a compiler setting. The compiler setting -fobjc-arc will cause the translation unit to be compiled with ARC enabled while -fno-objc-arc to compile without it. It's also a setting in the project to compile everything with ARC on or off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a build setting. In Xcode, click your project file, select Build Settings, search for `arc`:

[image]

For details about how you have to write your code with or without ARC, see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). This is not something that can be summarized in a short answer. You might also want to check out the WWDC '11 and '12 videos about ARC: [Introduction to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=323).

Comment: ah ok! thanks! learning what it is/how to use it now so only wanted to understand if it was a setting or what. Now i get it! :)